# Change base64 encoded Docker ENV variable during build process to decoded value

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile

For our GitLab runner we have some variables saved on GitLab. One of them is a base64 encoded `USER_DB_PASSWORD_ENCODED` variable.

I pass the variable to the Docker build command used for our tests and can access it like this in the Dockerfile:

```
ARG USER_DB_PASSWORD_ENCODED
ENV USER_DB_PASSWORD_ENCODED=${USER_DB_PASSWORD_ENCODED}
```

From here my app could access this `ENV` variable `USER_DB_PASSWORD_ENCODED`, but I need to decode it to be able to use it in the app. For this purpose I tried this sequence:

```
RUN echo "$USER_DB_PASSWORD_ENCODED" | base64 --decode > /temp
RUN USER_DB_PASSWORD_ENCODED=$(cat /temp); echo "Output: $USER_DB_PASSWORD_ENCODED"
ENV USER_DB_PASSWORD=$USER_DB_PASSWORD_ENCODED
RUN echo $USER_DB_PASSWORD
```

I decode the encoded variable into a `/temp` dir, try to assign that value to the existing variable, and try to assign that existing variable to a new variable, with the name that is actually used in the app.

The decoding works, the output `echo` shows me the decoded value correctly, but when I `echo` the new variable, it still shows me the decoded value.

How can I properly deal with an encoded variable and overwrite an existing/create a new `ENV` variable in a Dockerfile?

An alternative idea was to not define a separate `ENV` variable, but decode the value directly into a `.env` file in the directory where it is needed, e.g.

```
RUN echo "$USER_DB_PASSWORD_ENCODED" | base64 --decode > /api/.env
```

But then I have the problem of only getting the decoded value into the file, while I also need to prepend the value with `USER_DB_PASSWORD_ENCODED` for it to be recognized by the app

Comment: Putting the credential in the Dockerfile at all is a bad idea: anyone who gets a copy of the image can `docker inspect` it and see its `ENV` settings, and from there get your password back out.  Injecting at runtime, maybe with a `docker run -e` option, is a better approach, and you can base64 decode it when you do that.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, I have no influence on the `docker run` command. GitLab Runner detects changes and uses the image which I can provide and contains the repo clone and build-args I provide and whichever instructions I add in the image. No credentials are directly stored in the Dockerfile, but it has access to the environment variables defined through GitLab

Comment: The `ENV` line leaks your credentials into the final image.  If you can check out the repository at the CI layer and not in the Dockerfile that will be much safer.

Comment: The GitLab runner has access to our GitLab repo and checks it out directly from there. But the repo obviously also doesn't contain sensitive information, so I need to use the variables we set in GitLab. So now I'm only looking for ways to use a base64 encoded variable (unencoded variables work fine just as described above) or rather how to assign the unencoded value to an `ENV`

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I went with my alternative approach:

```
RUN echo -n "USER_DB_PASSWORD=" > api/.env
RUN echo -n "$USER_DB_PASSWORD_ENCODED" | base64 --decode >> api/.env
```

The first command creates a `.env` where it can be read from the application and writes the string `USER_DB_PASSWORD=` to it (without newline).

The second command appends the decoded value of the encoded and masked GitLab variable to the existing line in the existing `.env` file.

This way, the cleartext value is never visible in the job log and the container is destroyed after a few minutes of running the tests.